# Numpy advanced indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

I have arrays with the following shapes

```
voxel_grids : (128, 32, 32, 32)
indices : (128, 3, 1024)
```

I want to construct an array `scalar (128, 1024)` such that

```
scalar[i,j] = voxel_grids[i, indices[i, 0, j], indices[i, 1, j], indices[i,2,j]]
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this using numpy (advanced) indexing?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this -

```
m = voxel_grids.shape[0]
out = voxel_grids[np.arange(m)[:,None],indices[:,0],indices[:,1],indices[:,2]]
```

Other way would be to extract the three slices from `indices` into three variables and use them for indexing. This might not be any more efficient than the previous one, but might be a bit easier to eyes. It's shown below -

```
m = voxel_grids.shape[0]
x,y,z = indices.swapaxes(0,1)
out = voxel_grids[np.arange(m)[:,None],x,y,z]
```